Question about SGA1 Expose V.1 Corollary 1.5
I am quite a beginner at scheme theory, so apologies if I am missing something really obvious. I am trying to understand the proof of Corollary 1.5 in SGA 1's Expose V about scheme quotients. It's Page 105 in this typed version.
In particular, I'm struggling to see even the claim that if $X$ is affine over $Z$ then so is $Y$. Grothendieck's proof reduces the problem to that when $Z$ is affine, which then reduces to proving that if $X$ is affine then so is $Y$. But then he claims that $Y = \operatorname{Spec}(A^G)$ follows from Proposition 1.1 directly, which I don't understand. Of course the underlying structure sheaf matches (since $\mathscr{O}_Y \stackrel{\sim}{\to} p_* \mathscr{O}_X^G)$ but why does the topology match? I think it should follow from part (ii) of Proposition 1.1 but there $Y$ is a priori an affine scheme already.
Hope I am not missing something really obvious :(

Okay I did miss something obvious. The topology of $Y$ is precisely what Corollary 1.4 addresses!
